# How to test if a user is logged in?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to testing with Angular and tried to test the checkLogin function in my application.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {AuthenticationService} from "../../services/authentication.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

    username = 'TestUser'
    password = 'TestPassword'
    invalidLogin = false

    constructor(private router: Router,
                private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    checkLogin() {
        if (this.authenticationService.authenticate(this.username, this.password)
        ) {
            this.router.navigate([''])
            this.invalidLogin = false
        } else
            this.invalidLogin = true
    }

}
```

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {

    constructor() { }

    authenticate(username, password) {
        if (username === "TestUser" && password === "TestPassword") {
            sessionStorage.setItem('username', username)
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    isUserLoggedIn() {
        let user = sessionStorage.getItem('username')
        console.log(!(user === null))
        return !(user === null)
    }

}
```

I tried something like this but I'm getting the following error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'authenticate')

Comment: This is strange and should not happen. Are you sure that you are importing the correct `AuthenticationService`? Angular should then inject the service into the constructor, but it seems to be undefined. Can you try to recreate the behavior in a StackBlitz example?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

try to stop the server and run ng serve again

i test your code but it works for me
you can see this link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hrdcq3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fauthentication.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: The application works but the test doesnt :/

Comment: I test in HTML, and if I choose the right username and password it displays true if not it displays false